# is it possible to use the onchange event to save an array

Tags: reactjs, arrays, onchange

i tried using state array and using onchange event so it catches what i enter but it will save the array and make the array longer it wont update the elements i added before it always creates new elements , this is what i tried

Select.js

```
function Select({data, ...selectProps}) {;
        const {id , name} = data;
        return (
            <>
            <select {...selectProps}>
                <option defaultValue='#'>#</option>
                {data.map((item, index) =>
                    <option key={index} value={item.id}>{item.name}</option>
                )} 
            </select>
            </>
        )
};

export default Select;
```

InputTextarea.js

```
function InputTextarea({label, ...inputTextareaProps}){
    return (
        <>
            <label>{label}</label>
            <textarea {...inputTextareaProps}></textarea>
        </>
    )
};

export default InputTextarea;
```

index.js

```
const  mo = {title: "Răng", img: logo};

const data = [
    {
        id: 1, list: [
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "Răng dạng tam giác"
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                name: "Răng dạng oval"
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                name: "Răng dạng vuông"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2, list: [
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "KT răng trung bình"
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                name: "KT răng nhỏ"
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                name: "KT răng lớn"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 3, list: [
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "Chiều cao răng TB"
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                name: "Thân răng ngắn"
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                name: "Thân răng dài"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 4, list: [
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "Hình thái BT"
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                name: "Hình thái bất thường"
            }
        ]
    },
    { id: 5, name: "Khác", list: [], value: "" },
];

const Teeth = () => {

    const [obj, setObj] = useState({});
    const [array, setArray] = useState([]);
    console.log(obj);
    console.log(array);



        return(
        <>
            <div className="col-md-6 mt-10">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-6 mt-10 text-center">
                        <Title value={mo.title}></Title>
                        {data.map((item, index) => {
                        if (item.list.length === 0) {
                            return (
                                <InputTextarea key={index}
                                className="text-center form-control"
                                type="text"
                                name="typeNote"
                                onChange={(e) => {
                                    setObj({idDetail: item.id, typeNote: e.target.value});
                                    // array.push(obj);
                                    setArray([...array, obj])
                                }}
                                placeholder={item.name}
                                />
                                )
                            } else {
                                return (<Select 
                                className="form-control"
                                onChange={(e) => {
                                    setObj({idDetail: e.target.value});
                                    // array.push(obj);
                                     setArray([...array, obj])
                                }}
                                data={item.list} key={index} >
                                </Select>);
                            }
                        })}

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>      
        </>
    )
};

export default Teeth;
```

when i select or enter a new element i want it to update the existing elements and add new ones that don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are encountering the issue because you are updating the state with the same object reference `obj` in each iteration of the `map` function. When you update the state with the same object reference, all elements in the `array` state will point to the same object.

To fix this issue, you can create a new object for each iteration of the `map` function, instead of reusing the same `obj` object. Try this code:

```js
const Teeth = () => {
  const [array, setArray] = useState([]);

  const handleInputChange = (e, item) => {
    const newObj = { idDetail: item.id, typeNote: e.target.value };
    setArray((prevArray) => [...prevArray, newObj]);
  };

  const handleSelectChange = (e, item) => {
    const newObj = { idDetail: e.target.value };
    setArray((prevArray) => [...prevArray, newObj]);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="col-md-6 mt-10">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-6 mt-10 text-center">
            <Title value={mo.title}></Title>
            {data.map((item, index) => {
              if (item.list.length === 0) {
                return (
                  <InputTextarea
                    key={index}
                    className="text-center form-control"
                    type="text"
                    name="typeNote"
                    onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, item)}
                    placeholder={item.name}
                  />
                );
              } else {
                return (
                  <Select
                    className="form-control"
                    onChange={(e) => handleSelectChange(e, item)}
                    data={item.list}
                    key={index}
                  ></Select>
                );
              }
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Teeth;
```

I've introduced two separate functions `handleInputChange` and `handleSelectChange` to handle the `onChange` events for the `InputTextarea` and `Select` components, respectively. These functions create a new object `newObj` with the necessary properties and then update the `array` state using thee spread syntax and the previous state.

By creating a new object for each iteration, you ensure that each element in the `array` state is a distinct object and correctly reprsents the data entered or selected for each item.

Comment: thank you for your help, but i want when i enter or select a value to update the existing one, and if not, add a new array element